# Writing tests that don't fail when Supervised processes die

Tags: erlang, erlang-otp, elixir, erlang-supervisor

I'm writing a few tests in ExUnit to illustrate how different Supervisor strategies work. I had planned to test results by intentionally causing spawned processes to fail, and then testing the restarted processes' output.

Thus far I have been unsuccessful in creating passing tests, as the initial process failure causes the test to fail. I have tried capturing the errors (try/catch) in both the Supervisor/GenServer implementation and the test implementation, but I have not been able to capture any and avoid the test failure.

1. Is there any way to capture these errors so that they do not trigger a test failure?
2. Is there a better/different means of testing different supervisor strategies?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to careful with your links. When you start a supervisor, it is linked to the current process, so if you crash the supervisor (or any other linked process), it will cause the test to crash too.

You can change this behaviour by setting `Process.flag(:trap_exit, true)` now links won't trigger crashes and instead you will be able to find messages of format `{:EXIT, pid, reason}` in your mailbox.

This is a fine approach for testing but for production or in general you likely want to setup some sort of monitor.

Comment: I'm having difficulty determining where the Process.flag should go. Currently, the links are structured as follows: Test -> Supervisor -> GenServer. The Test then causes the GenServer to throw an ArgumentError and crash. I have been unsuccessful at capturing the errors at any level except the Test level.

When capturing at the Test level, I've initialized the GenServer within the Test module and provided it to the Supervisor. The issue I encountered with this is that the GenServer is now already running and can't be started as a worker.

Any thoughts on how I should structure the calls?

Comment: @arami: take a look at https://github.com/mprymek/suptest - you must remove the application module from mix.exs so the application is not started automatically and then start it manually (see https://github.com/mprymek/suptest/blob/master/test/suptest_test.exs )

Answer (score 1):

Because I was intentionally causing a process to fail and wanted to ignore this failure within the ExUnit test, I ended up using catch_exit/1 to prevent the test process from failing.